# Sempre que o botão for clicado um novo quadrado deve aparecer na tela

Tags: javascript, html

```
<button class='botao' id='btnCriar' onClick="gerarQuadrado()">Gerar novo</button>
<div id="app">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<script>
    var btnCriar = document.querySelector('#btnCriar')
    btnCriar.style.color = '#fff'
    btnCriar.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    btnCriar.style.backgroundColor = '#424242';
    btnCriar.style.border = 'solid #ddd';
    btnCriar.style.width = '200px';
    btnCriar.style.height = '40px';
    btnCriar.style.marginLeft = '45%';

    btnCriar.onclick = function gerarQuadrado() {
        var boxElement = document.querySelector('.box');
        boxElement.style.width = '180px';
        boxElement.style.height = '180px';
        boxElement.style.margin = '10px';
        boxElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
    }    
</script>
```

Estou travado nessa parte de gerar um novo quadrado, no momento ele apenas gera um elemento.

Comment: Quando se fala "um novo quadrado" entende-se que já existe um ou estou enganado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade vc não tem que clonar o elemento, ao meu ver seria melhor vc criar o elemento usando o método `createElement()` eu tb não indicaria vc escrever o CSS dessa forma existem formais mais simples para isso, mas está ai um exemplo usando o máximo do seu código para ficar mais didático para vc nesse momento

```js
var btnCriar = document.querySelector('#btnCriar')
btnCriar.style.color = '#fff'
btnCriar.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
btnCriar.style.backgroundColor = '#424242';
btnCriar.style.border = 'solid #ddd';
btnCriar.style.width = '200px';
btnCriar.style.height = '40px';
btnCriar.style.marginLeft = '45%';

function gerarQuadrado() {

    let boxElement = document.createElement("div");
    boxElement.style.width = '180px';
    boxElement.style.height = '180px';
    boxElement.style.margin = '10px';
    boxElement.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';

//adiciona a classe .box na div criada
boxElement.classList.add('box');

    document.body.appendChild(boxElement);
}
```

```html
<button class='botao' id='btnCriar' onClick="gerarQuadrado()">Gerar novo</button>
<div id="app">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `btnCriar.onclick = function gerarQuadrado() {      
            var boxElement = document.createElement("div");  
            boxElement.setAttribute("class", "box");
            containerBoxElement.appendChild(boxElement);  
        }` Utilizei desta forma e funcionou tbm.

Comment: @GustavoLopes sim daria certo tb

Answer (score 3):

a pergunta ..... "um novo quadrado" faz supor que já exista um.

Método  [insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) - pode agregar conteúdo antes ou depois do conteúdo atual.

Este método faz, basicamente, o que a propriedade .innerHTML faz, porém, é possível
escolher a posição onde o novo html será inserido. `insertAdjacentHTML(posição, elemento)`.

```js
function gerarQuadrado() {
  var h = document.getElementById("box");
    //os dois parâmetos a seguir são
    //primeiro - afterend: Insere o HTML depois do elemento
    //segundo - o elemento que será adicionada
  h.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", "<div id='box' class='box'></div>");
}
```

```css
.box    {
width : 90px;
height : 90px;
margin : 10px;
background-color : #f00;
}
```

```html
<button class='botao' id='btnCriar' onclick="gerarQuadrado()">Gerar novo</button>

<div id="app">
    <div id="box" class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function gerarQuadrado() {

  var boxElement = document.createElement("div");

  boxElement.style.width = "100px";
  boxElement.style.height = "100px";
  boxElement.style.backgroundColor = "#f00";
  boxElement.style.margin = "10px";

  var container = document.getElementById("box")
  container.appendChild(boxElement)
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="create" onclick="gerarQuadrado()">Criar Quadrado</button>
  <div id="box"></div>

</body>
```

Você precisa criar uma nova div toda vez que o botão for clicado.

Answer (score -1):

Seria algo parecido com isso?

```
function gerarQuadrado(){
  var divSelecionada = $("#app .box:first");
  var divNova = divSelecionada.clone();
  divNova.fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Comment: Ele continuou igual, precisava que na tela gerasse mais um, assim ficando dois quadrados iguais